# aws credentials are not working from android sample app

Tags: java, android, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the sample app provided from the AWS MOBILE HUB and when I run it works. But whenever i copy the amazonaws folder to my project I get an error with regards to the credentials. This the error i get when i try to run a query to dynamodb

```
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::033145769257:assumed-role/getitdelivery_unauth_MOBILEHUB_927752501/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:033145769257:table/getitdelivery-mobilehub-927752501-Deliveries/index/Todays_Order (Service: AmazonDynamoDB; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: JEDMKDQ6JMOTVPIMF85VJHSMGFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at your IAM Policy. Mobile Hub configures all of this for you with their generated sample application, but since you copied some things to your own project, you might need to update the policy so that your unauth role has permission to do: `dynamodb:Query` on resource: `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:033145769257:table/getitdelivery-mobilehub-927752501-Deliveries/index/Todays_Order`.

An example of what the policy should look like is found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html

Comment: I took a look at that and everything looks fines to me. It look like am hitting the correct resources and I have the rights.

Comment: I have double checked all that - I have an app written a few months ago that used to work, but no longer does. I re-generated a sample app and it uses the same credientials, and that one works. I revoked the query permission and the sample app gives the same exact error that my app is giving. An further suggestions for why two apps using the same credentials would have one fail to be authorized and the other works?